# Php auto add message to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, chat

i have made a chat, it sends user message to database. However i have an "CHAT BOT" and i want that it insert certain text into mysql every 5 minutes. Is that possible?

Here is how it should add it to database:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO chatMessages (`id`, `user`, `message`) VALUES ('', '$userID', 'Hello, i am an automated CHAT BOT.') ");
```

Is it possible to do with PHP or do i need JavaScript for it? I hope i can get a help from here.

I haven't tried anything yet since i do not work does it work with PHP.

Comment: Why should it insert same messages to database?

Comment: You want to use an ajax call to a php script that holds the code for inserting a message. Wrap the ajax in a setInterval for doing this every x minutes.

Comment: That text was just full example.

Comment: Don't use the deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Use mysqli or better yet, PDO instead. You're probably also open to SQL Injections. When you have changed your mysql-funcitons to mysqli or PDO, use prepared statements.

Comment: Use Event Scheduler, [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html)